# Swagger - Personalización de default.yaml en GeneXus

Tags: genexus, rest, swagger

Estoy usando la generación por defecto del archivo `.yaml` y es muy útil. Sin embargo, me gustaría poder complementarlo con otros tags. Por ejemplo, la descripción del WebService o de las variables, si son requeridos, etc...

¿Hay forma de agregar información en GeneXus y que sea tenida en cuenta en el `.yaml? los tags "required", "description", "summary"

Revisé estos links y en principio no encuentro la forma:
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31859,Generate+Open+API+interface+property,
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30776,Documenting+RestFul+services,

Gracias.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español! Antes de realizar una pregunta tan amplia deberías de investigar las especificaciones de los componentes que estás usando y después preguntar exactamente qué "tag" tienes problemas para implementar. Revisa nuestra ayuda sobre [cómo hacer una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y las [preguntas que corresponden a este sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). De lo contrario podría no tener la suficiente atención al no poder ofrecerte una única respuesta.

Comment: En GeneXus hoy no hay forma de hacerlo, se podrían agregar los tags "description" y "summary" automáticamente a partir de la descripción de las variables y del web service. En los BCs REST sí tienen esta información. El _work arround_ hoy sería cambiarlo a mano en el archivo, pero los cambios los vas a perder cada vez que se genere.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la respuesta.